integral of all distances from vertex to base
I have a triangle with three sides known. Base is c. I am trying to think of a generalized measure of the "effort of connecting vertex C to the line segment AB (whose length is c).
One such measure could be the sum of all lines drawn from vertex C to every point on line AB. What is the sum of all possible lines drawn from vertex C to the base? I do not have a background in calculus, so I am looking for a algebraic explanation/answer. ChatGPT provided an approximation as c/6(a+b+4h) where h is the median, c is the base and a and b are the other two sides.
Further, can triangular distributions also be used here, specifically pdf?
